# Android-Sign in via Google plus "An internal error has occured"

Tags: android, google-plus, google-oauth

I have some problem which this link talk about:
["An internal error occurred" with integration of Google Plus Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762904/an-internal-error-occurred-at-time-of-integration-of-google-plus)
and this link:
[Google plus client "An internal error occured"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987040/google-plus-client-an-internal-error-occured)
but the latest one not usful for me,
in the first link somebody suggest this solution:
This can happen when you haven't set the signature for the client ID in your API console project, or if you copied the wrong key value from keytool

but I set the signature for the client ID as the instructions in this link:
https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android#install-sdk

I generated SHA1 from export the project and take the SHA1 from console.

and I created client ID and put the package name and the SHA1

and when I press signin Button I received this Toast message: "An internal error has occurred"

Please I need any idea to do to solve this problem

and finally this is my code

```
public class GoogleActivity extends Activity implements
ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, OnClickListener,
OnAccessRevokedListener, PlusClient.OnPersonLoadedListener {

private static final String TAG = "SignInTestActivity";

// A magic number we will use to know that our sign-in error
// resolution activity has completed.
private static final int OUR_REQUEST_CODE = 49404;

// The core Google+ client.
private PlusClient mPlusClient;

// A flag to stop multiple dialogues appearing for the user.
private boolean mResolveOnFail;

// We can store the connection result from a failed connect()
// attempt in order to make the application feel a bit more
// responsive for the user.
private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

// A progress dialog to display when the user is connecting in
// case there is a delay in any of the dialogs being ready.
private ProgressDialog mConnectionProgressDialog;

// Person information.
String firstName,lastName,Nationality,gender,email,birthDay;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_google);
// We pass through this for all three arguments, specifying the:
// 1. Context
// 2. Object to call onConnected and onDisconnected on
// 3. Object to call onConnectionFailed on
mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
        .setVisibleActivities("http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity")
        .build();

// We use mResolveOnFail as a flag to say whether we should trigger
// the resolution of a connectionFailed ConnectionResult.
mResolveOnFail = false;

// Connect our sign in, sign out and disconnect buttons.
findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);
findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(this);
findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(this);
findViewById(R.id.button2).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
findViewById(R.id.button3).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

// Configure the ProgressDialog that will be shown if there is a
// delay in presenting the user with the next sign in step.
mConnectionProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
mConnectionProgressDialog.setMessage("Signing in...");
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();
Log.v(TAG, "Start");
// Every time we start we want to try to connect. If it
// succeeds we'll get an onConnected() callback. If it
// fails we'll get onConnectionFailed(), with a result!
mPlusClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
super.onStop();
Log.v(TAG, "Stop");
// It can be a little costly to keep the connection open
// to Google Play Services, so each time our activity is
// stopped we should disconnect.
mPlusClient.disconnect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
Log.v(TAG, "ConnectionFailed");
// Most of the time, the connection will fail with a
// user resolvable result. We can store that in our
// mConnectionResult property ready for to be used
// when the user clicks the sign-in button.
if (result.hasResolution()) {
    mConnectionResult = result;
    if (mResolveOnFail) {
        // This is a local helper function that starts
        // the resolution of the problem, which may be
        // showing the user an account chooser or similar.
        startResolution();
    }
}
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
//--- We can get the oAuth 2.0 access token we are using.
Log.v(TAG, "Connected.");

// Turn off the flag, so if the user signs out they'll have to
// tap to sign in again.
mResolveOnFail = false;

// Hide the progress dialog if its showing.
mConnectionProgressDialog.dismiss();

// Hide the sign in button, show the sign out buttons.
findViewById(R.id.button1).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
findViewById(R.id.button2).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
findViewById(R.id.button3).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
String accountName = mPlusClient.getAccountName();

//-- fetch person info
mPlusClient.loadPerson(this, "me");

Toast.makeText(this, accountName + " is connected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

// Retrieve the oAuth 2.0 access token.
final Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
AsyncTask task = new AsyncTask() {
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        String scope = "oauth2:" + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN;

        try {
            // We can retrieve the token to check via
            // tokeninfo or to pass to a service-side
            // application.
            String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context,
                    mPlusClient.getAccountName(), scope);
        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
            // This error is recoverable, so we could fix this
            // by displaying the intent to the user.
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
};

task.execute((Void) null);
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
// Bye!
Log.v(TAG, "Disconnected. Bye!");
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
    Intent intent) {
Log.v(TAG, "ActivityResult: " + requestCode);
if (requestCode == OUR_REQUEST_CODE && responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
    // If we have a successful result, we will want to be able to
    // resolve any further errors, so turn on resolution with our
    // flag.
    mResolveOnFail = true;
    // If we have a successful result, lets call connect() again. If
    // there are any more errors to resolve we'll get our
    // onConnectionFailed, but if not, we'll get onConnected.
    mPlusClient.connect();
} else if (requestCode == OUR_REQUEST_CODE && responseCode != RESULT_OK) {
    // If we've got an error we can't resolve, we're no
    // longer in the midst of signing in, so we can stop
    // the progress spinner.
    mConnectionProgressDialog.dismiss();
}
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
switch (view.getId()) {
case R.id.button1:
    Log.v(TAG, "Tapped sign in");
    if (!mPlusClient.isConnected()) {
        // Show the dialog as we are now signing in.
        mConnectionProgressDialog.show();
        // Make sure that we will start the resolution (e.g. fire the
        // intent and pop up a dialog for the user) for any errors
        // that come in.
        mResolveOnFail = true;
        // We should always have a connection result ready to resolve,
        // so we can start that process.
        if (mConnectionResult != null) {
            startResolution();
        } else {
            // If we don't have one though, we can start connect in
            // order to retrieve one.
            mPlusClient.connect();
        }
    }
    break;
case R.id.button2:
    Log.v(TAG, "Tapped sign out");
    // We only want to sign out if we're connected.
    if (mPlusClient.isConnected()) {
        // Clear the default account in order to allow the user
        // to potentially choose a different account from the
        // account chooser.
        mPlusClient.clearDefaultAccount();

        // Disconnect from Google Play Services, then reconnect in
        // order to restart the process from scratch.
        mPlusClient.disconnect();
        mPlusClient.connect();

        // Hide the sign out buttons, show the sign in button.
        findViewById(R.id.button1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.button2)
                .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.button3).setVisibility(
                View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    break;
case R.id.button3:
    Log.v(TAG, "Tapped disconnect");
    if (mPlusClient.isConnected()) {
        // Clear the default account as in the Sign Out.
        mPlusClient.clearDefaultAccount();

        // Go away and revoke access to this entire application.
        // This will call back to onAccessRevoked when it is
        // complete as it needs to go away to the Google
        // authentication servers to revoke all token.
        mPlusClient.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(this);
    }
    break;
default:
    // Unknown id.
}
}

@Override
public void onAccessRevoked(ConnectionResult status) {
// mPlusClient is now disconnected and access has been revoked.
// We should now delete any data we need to comply with the
// developer properties. To reset ourselves to the original state,
// we should now connect again. We don't have to disconnect as that
// happens as part of the call.
mPlusClient.connect();

// Hide the sign out buttons, show the sign in button.
findViewById(R.id.button1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
findViewById(R.id.button2).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
findViewById(R.id.button3).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

/**
* A helper method to flip the mResolveOnFail flag and start the resolution
* of the ConnenctionResult from the failed connect() call.
*/

private void startResolution() {
try {
    // Don't start another resolution now until we have a
    // result from the activity we're about to start.
    mResolveOnFail = false;
    // If we can resolve the error, then call start resolution
    // and pass it an integer tag we can use to track. This means
    // that when we get the onActivityResult callback we'll know
    // its from being started here.
    mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, OUR_REQUEST_CODE);
} catch (SendIntentException e) {
    // Any problems, just try to connect() again so we get a new
    // ConnectionResult.
    mPlusClient.connect();
}
}

@Override
public void onPersonLoaded(ConnectionResult status, Person person) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

//fetch(status, person);    
try
{
if (status.getErrorCode() == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) 
{
    Log.d(TAG, "Display Name: " + person.getDisplayName());

    firstName = person.getName().getGivenName();
    Toast.makeText(this, firstName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    lastName = person.getName().getFamilyName();
    Toast.makeText(this, lastName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    if(person.getGender() == 0)
        gender = "male";
    else if(person.getGender() == 1)
        gender = "female";
    else 
        gender = "other";
    Toast.makeText(this, gender, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    List<Person.PlacesLived> cites =person.getPlacesLived();
    if(cites!=null)
    {
        Nationality = cites.get(0).toString();
        Toast.makeText(this, Nationality, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "Null Nationality", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    birthDay = person.getBirthday();
    Toast.makeText(this, birthDay, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    List<Emails> emails = person.getEmails();
    if(emails !=null)
    {
        email = emails.get(0).getValue();
        Toast.makeText(this, email, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, person.getDisplayName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    /*TextView name =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView Gender =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    TextView mail =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    TextView BD =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    TextView Current =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);

    name.setText(person.getName().getFamilyName());
    Gender.setText(person.getGender());
    mail.setText(person.getEmails().get(0).toString());
    BD.setText(person.getBirthday());
    Current.setText(person.getCurrentLocation());*/

}
else
    Toast.makeText(this, "no result", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

}

Comment: also when I run Google plus Sample I faced the same Toas message
although I create new client ID for it and add SHA1
Please I need help, What should I do??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by get SHA from cmd not from exported file becuase I am running the project via mobile not via getting APK file when I should run project via getting apk file I must get the SHA from exported file

Comment: Get SHA from cmd? Can you please clarify?

Comment: When you test on Eclipse you  need to get the SHA-1 fingerprint of the certificate from command line: In a terminal, run the the Keytool utility by write the following:
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v

•Press enter
•the password is: android
•press enter
•Copy the SHA1 hash

Comment: you should replace this: ~/.android/debug.keystore >> with your debug.keystore location on your device

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error message. My problem was solved by changing

.setScopes("PLUS_LOGIN")

to

.setScopes(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN)