# Android Studio PlusClient "Internal Error"

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0, google-play-services

Ok, I've been messing with this for a few days and can't seem to get G+ to connect in my app. I am using Android Studio 0.4.3. I followed [this](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started) tutorial provided by Google to the T with no luck. My code currently resembles [this example](https://gist.github.com/ianbarber/5170508) somebody has provided on github. Nothing I try seems to work. I have looked though [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762904/an-internal-error-occurred-with-integration-of-google-plus-login), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987040/google-plus-client-an-internal-error-occured), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503865/android-sign-in-via-google-plus-an-internal-error-has-occured) and just about every other similar question floating around stack or other forums. I followed [the tutorial](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started) for setting up the OAuth 2.0 code and still I receive the "internal error" toast.

```
import com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.Scopes;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusClient;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusClient.OnAccessRevokedListener;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LogIn extends Activity implements
    ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, OnClickListener,
    OnAccessRevokedListener {

private static final String TAG = "SignInTestActivity";

static final String[] SCOPES = new String[] { Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN };

// A magic number we will use to know that our sign-in error
// resolution activity has completed.
private static final int OUR_REQUEST_CODE = 9000;

// The core Google+ client.
private PlusClient mPlusClient;

// A flag to stop multiple dialogues appearing for the user.
private boolean mResolveOnFail;

// We can store the connection result from a failed connect()
// attempt in order to make the application feel a bit more
// responsive for the user.
private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

// A progress dialog to display when the user is connecting in
// case there is a delay in any of the dialogs being ready.
private ProgressDialog mConnectionProgressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    // We pass through this for all three arguments, specifying the:
    // 1. Context
    // 2. Object to call onConnected and onDisconnected on
    // 3. Object to call onConnectionFailed on
    mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
            .setActions("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity", "http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity")
            .setScopes(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN)  // recommended login scope for social features
         // .setScopes("profile")       // alternative basic login scope
            .build();

    // We use mResolveOnFail as a flag to say whether we should trigger
    // the resolution of a connectionFailed ConnectionResult.
    mResolveOnFail = false;

    // Connect our sign in, sign out and disconnect buttons.
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);

    // Configure the ProgressDialog that will be shown if there is a
    // delay in presenting the user with the next sign in step.
    mConnectionProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mConnectionProgressDialog.setMessage("Signing in...");
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.v(TAG, "Start");
    // Every time we start we want to try to connect. If it
    // succeeds we'll get an onConnected() callback. If it
    // fails we'll get onConnectionFailed(), with a result!
    mPlusClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.v(TAG, "Stop");
    // It can be a little costly to keep the connection open
    // to Google Play Services, so each time our activity is
    // stopped we should disconnect.
    mPlusClient.disconnect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    Log.v(TAG, "ConnectionFailed");
    Toast.makeText(this, "connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // Most of the time, the connection will fail with a
    // user resolvable result. We can store that in our
    // mConnectionResult property ready for to be used
    // when the user clicks the sign-in button.
    if (result.hasResolution()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "has resolution - "+result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mConnectionResult = result;
        if (mResolveOnFail) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "resolveOnFail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // This is a local helper function that starts
            // the resolution of the problem, which may be
            // showing the user an account chooser or similar.
            startResolution();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    // Yay! We can get the oAuth 2.0 access token we are using.
    Log.v(TAG, "Connected. Yay!");
    String accountName = mPlusClient.getAccountName();
    Toast.makeText(this, accountName + " is connected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // Turn off the flag, so if the user signs out they'll have to
    // tap to sign in again.
    mResolveOnFail = false;

    // Hide the progress dialog if its showing.
    mConnectionProgressDialog.dismiss();

    // Hide the sign in button, show the sign out buttons.
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    // Retrieve the oAuth 2.0 access token.
    final Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
    AsyncTask task = new AsyncTask() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            String scope = "oauth2:" + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN;
            try {
                // We can retrieve the token to check via
                // tokeninfo or to pass to a service-side
                // application.
                String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context,
                        mPlusClient.getAccountName(), scope);
            } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
                // This error is recoverable, so we could fix this
                // by displaying the intent to the user.
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
    task.execute((Void) null);
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    // Bye!
    Log.v(TAG, "Disconnected. Bye!");
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
    Log.v(TAG, "ActivityResult: " + requestCode);
    Toast.makeText(this, "ActivityResult: " + requestCode+" -- "+responseCode+" "+RESULT_OK, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (requestCode == OUR_REQUEST_CODE && responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // If we have a successful result, we will want to be able to
        // resolve any further errors, so turn on resolution with our
        // flag.
        mResolveOnFail = true;
        // If we have a successful result, lets call connect() again. If
        // there are any more errors to resolve we'll get our
        // onConnectionFailed, but if not, we'll get onConnected.
        mPlusClient.connect();
    } else if (requestCode == OUR_REQUEST_CODE && responseCode != RESULT_OK) {
        // If we've got an error we can't resolve, we're no
        // longer in the midst of signing in, so we can stop
        // the progress spinner.

        mConnectionProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.sign_in_button:
            Log.v(TAG, "Tapped sign in");
            if (!mPlusClient.isConnected()) {
                // Show the dialog as we are now signing in.
                mConnectionProgressDialog.show();
                // Make sure that we will start the resolution (e.g. fire the
                // intent and pop up a dialog for the user) for any errors
                // that come in.
                mResolveOnFail = true;
                // We should always have a connection result ready to resolve,
                // so we can start that process.
                if (mConnectionResult != null) {
                    startResolution();
                } else {
                    // If we don't have one though, we can start connect in
                    // order to retrieve one.
                    mPlusClient.connect();
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            // Unknown id.
    }
}

@Override
public void onAccessRevoked(ConnectionResult status) {
    // mPlusClient is now disconnected and access has been revoked.
    // We should now delete any data we need to comply with the
    // developer properties. To reset ourselves to the original state,
    // we should now connect again. We don't have to disconnect as that
    // happens as part of the call.
    mPlusClient.connect();

    // Hide the sign out buttons, show the sign in button.
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

/**
 * A helper method to flip the mResolveOnFail flag and start the resolution
 * of the ConnenctionResult from the failed connect() call.
 */
private void startResolution() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "resolving", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    try {
        // Don't start another resolution now until we have a
        // result from the activity we're about to start.
        mResolveOnFail = false;
        // If we can resolve the error, then call start resolution
        // and pass it an integer tag we can use to track. This means
        // that when we get the onActivityResult callback we'll know
        // its from being started here.
        mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, OUR_REQUEST_CODE);
    } catch (SendIntentException e) {
        // Any problems, just try to connect() again so we get a new
        // ConnectionResult.
        mPlusClient.connect();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: No external links please, and a concise, precise description of your problem, illustrated with the **relevant** code only.  You should put in about 10 times as much effort into writing your question as you expect people to put into answering it.  Personally, if I see external links (click here to see my code) or lots of links to read or a mass of code, I just move onto the next question.

Comment: @Simon I had all my code in this thread but it was telling me parts of my code weren't formatted correctly when it was so I moved everything to pastebin. Sorry for the external links. I you look at any of my other threads I have created, you would see that my posts are usually quite detailed. I explained my problem as it occurs. What details would you like me to add?

Comment: @Simon People usually complain when there is only a fragment of code provided with an error like this. Which is why I provided my entire code on pastebin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what was wrong, but I decided to start over from scratch and the issue seemed to work itself out -_-